# Ignore/ skip opening and the closing script tags and contents

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to ask for help in writing a small check for a string that contains html tags and can contains also JavaScript tags.
I want to be able to check the string and skip any content that is within the tags:

```
<script>ignore whatever within</script>
```

I am stripping the html from extra spaces, tabs and line breaks, and some of the html has inline JavaScript, which is not ideal but right now I have to work around it.

Here is an example, a modest method, and where I would like to add the new check:

```
Public Shared Function MinifyStringContent(ByVal strContent As String) As String
    Dim rtnStringContent As String = ""
    If Not IsNothing(strContent) AndAlso strContent <> "" Then
        rtnStringContent = strContent.ToString.Replace(vbCrLf, "").Replace("  ", " ").Replace(vbTab, "")
    End If
    Return rtnStringContent.Trim()
End Function
```

Can I get an idea on how to do this by adding it to the existing code?

Thank you for your help.

---

I am trying to install the web.optimization package, but the installation gets rolled back. I get:

Install failed. Rolling back...

Install-Package : Project unavailable.

At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

- CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], COMException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Any idea on how can I fix this?

Thank you.

---

I changed my method to use the HtmlAgilityPack.
This is the new code:

```
    Public Shared Function MinifyStringContent(ByVal strContent As String) As String
    Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    doc.Load(strContent)
    If Not IsNothing(strContent) AndAlso strContent <> "" Then
        For Each textnode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")
            If Not textnode.ParentNode.Name = "script" Then
                textnode.InnerHtml = textnode.InnerText.Replace(vbCrLf, "").Replace("  ", " ").Replace(vbTab, "")
            End If
        Next
    End If
    Return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
End Function
```

But the code break in this part:

```
doc.Load(strContent)
```

The error reads: Illegal characters in path.

The method is called from the Render method in BasePage.vb:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
    Dim stringWriter As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter
    Dim htmlWriter As HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)

    MyBase.Render(htmlWriter)
    Dim html As String = stringWriter.ToString()
    html = Functions.MinifyStringContent(html)
    writer.Write(html)
End Sub
```

Can someone help me to identify what I am doing incorrectly?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should look into using the `System.Web.Optimization` framework from Microsoft, on Nuget.  There's no need to write your own and possibly have issues when someone else has done the work.

Comment: HTML is difficult, so in general you should use a library to parse it, such as the HTMLAgilityPack.